# Oracle JET validator required is not working?

Tags: javascript, oracle-jet

[image]

I'm assuming that the front-end code is enough to check the empty validation like html(required) do.

Comment: Which version of Oracle JET are you using?

Comment: "oraclejet": "~3.1.0"

Answer (score 0):

The `required` attribute simply puts the asterisk above the label of the input (assuming you have a label). It doesn't perform any validation, and neither does your translations. You need the `validators` attribute. Something like this:

```
<input 
    id="newCompanyName" 
    type="text" 
    required="required" 
    placeholder="at least 3 characters" 
    data-bind="ojComponent: {
      component: 'ojInputText', 
      value: newCompanyName, 
      validators: [{
        type: 'regExp', 
        options: {
          pattern: '.{3,}', 
          messageDetail: 'Enter at least 3 characters'}}]}">
```

Comment: no, it validates if no value in the input. You only need to put ```required```, no equals, nothing more. If the input is empty it displays the message. You can also force it when pressing a button by calling document.getElementById(yourElementId).validate();

Comment: @JoelCarneiro are you referring to version 3.1.0?

Comment: nice catch. I missed that info in the comments below. I spoke as it was the 7.x.x versions